# Error pushing Node.js code hosted on remote Linux machine(DigitalOcean) to GitHub repository using ssh connection

Tags: git, github, ssh, linux-kernel, git-bash

I am constantly getting the error:
error as shown in terminal

[image]

I have set up my SSH key on my local machine and added it to my GitHub account.
Here are the steps I have taken:

1. Inside GitBash I generated an SSH key pair using the following command: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"`
2. files `id_ed25519` and `id_ed25519.pub` were generated.
3. I copied the contents of the public key (`id_ed25519.pub`) by running: `cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub`
4. On GitHub I navigated to my account settings and added the copied public key as a new SSH key.
5. Back on the remote Linux server, I accessed the `authorized_keys` file located in the `~/.ssh/` directory and pasted the contents of the public key.

Now, when I try to push my code from the remote Linux server to the Git repository using the command `git push origin main`, I receive the following error message:

"git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

I have double-checked that the SSH key is correctly configured and the repository's URL is set as the origin. I also verified that the `authorized_keys` file on the remote server contains the correct public key.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully push my code from the remote Linux server to the Git repository. Thank you for your assistance.

[image]

[image]

- expected the code to be pushed into the main repository but public key error is coming,I have checked the public key in both local folder and github ,the signature is same but still the error  is shown*

Comment: How did you connect to the remote Linux server? Did you use that key, and if so, did you forward your agent?

Comment: @JimRedmond I have my node app opened in vs code using remote ssh connection, I have added the private key to the ssh agent using "ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519" also I put the public key into the remote linux server inside using  "nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys".

Comment: Where did you run `ssh-add`? On your own system or on the remote? If the private key isn't on the remote server, either directly or as part of a forwarded agent, then it won't be available to use when the remote server connects to GitHub. (You can forward the agent when you SSH to the remote server: `ssh -A remote-server-name`)